# Add comment via API as company page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

Is there any way to comment some object on facebook as company page (not from personal account)? We have comment.add method, but I'm not able to give permissions for my app from company page (I have to switch to my personal profile). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you'll have to get an `app access_token` and use that token when making the post.  You can read more here - on the [Facebook Authentication Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for more information about how to retrieve your app `access_token`.  (Scroll down to `App Login`)

Comment: Thanks, I added scope=manage_pages to oauth dialog URL and now my app can manage my company page :)

Comment: Happy to help, friend!  Please mark this question as answered.